# Create an Email listener which can trigger some task once an email is received from a particular user/Email/Subject

Tags: c#, email, outlook, listener

I have a task which is sending a file as an attachment to a particular set of group. The task is dependent on a mail from a particular user/subject.Once a  specific mail  is  received , the task will kick off. Now this is being done manually. I need to create an Email listener to listen to mailbox for an incoming mail, just like there is a FileSystemListener which indicates any changes in the Directory.

Can it be done?. If yes then any supporting piece of code  on this would be greatly appreciated

Entire scenario in the context of OUTLOOK mailbox.

Spare my ignorance as i'm new to this.

Comment: Outlook has an entire rule system built in, that can perform a variety of tasks, including launching applications. Would it work for you? Who knows, since we don't know the nature of the task at hand. You may be able to just do this using rules, no programming involved.

Comment: @Damien, Good point, But that would not come to help when there a need to perform non outlook operations. Or would it?

Comment: I'll repeat part of my first comment - "... including launching applications"

Comment: I prefer to use some code for that instead of rules. Is there a way for that?